# Parse SNMP output in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need to process the text output from the below command:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c community 192.168.122.15 .1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.39
```

The Original output is:

`SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.39.252.200.151.233.54.69.197.39.5.77 = STRING: "Android"`

I need the output to look like

```
197.39.5.77="Android"
```

`197.39.5.77` is the last four digits before the `=` sign.

Answer (score 2):

If the prefix is completely static, just remove it.

```
result=$(snmpwalk -v2c -c community 192.168.122.15 .1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.39)
result=${result#'SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.39.252.200.151.233.54.69.'}
echo "${result/ = STRING: /}"
```

Or you could do

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=' .'
set $($(snmpwalk -v2c -c community 192.168.122.15 .1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.39)
IFS=$oldIFS
shift 16
result="$1.$2.$3.$4=$7"
```

The numeric argument to `shift` and the `${var/str/subst}` construct are Bashisms.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c community 192.168.122.15 .1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.39 \
| sed -e 's/.*\.\([0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\{3\}\).*\(".*"\)/\1=\3/'
```

Or with `bash` proper:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c community 192.168.122.15 .1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.39 \
| while read a b c; do echo ${a#${a%*.*.*.*.*}.}=\"${c#*\"}; done
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked with one of the output only

197.39.5.3="Android"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises
0.0.0.0=14823

However the original result is 

SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.39.240.90.9.122.245.208.197.39.7.27 = STRING: "Android"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.39.240.90.9.149.138.172.197.39.7.47 = STRING: "Android"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.39.240.231.126.16.33.84.197.39.7.32 = STRING: "Android"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.39.240.231.126.170.135.132.197.39.7.25 = ""


and others

Answer (score 0):

Pipe through `sed` as shown below:

```
$ snmpwalk -v2c -c community 192.168.122.15 .1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.39 | sed -r 's/.*\.([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+) = .*: (.*)/\1=\2/g'
197.39.5.77="Android"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep -Eo '(\.[0-9]{1,3}){4}\s*=.*$' | sed -r 'sed -r 's/\s*=[^:]+:/=/;s/^\.//'`

First part is to isolate the end of the line with a good address followed with `=`; the second part with `sed` erases any string between `=` and `:`, and erases also the first dot before IPv4 address. For compactness, `grep` is searching for 4 times a dot followed with at most 3 digits.

Comment: Thanks, this is working perfectly, but it returns a space as below
197.39.33.94 = "Android"
I can use cut to remove this space

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and support

Comment: @KareemHamed Or you can modify the first s-command in sed to remove the extra space(s); see my update.